# remove info and time from ROS_INFO

Tags: ros, ros-info, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I am hoping there is some way I could remove the following from ROS_INFO.

[ INFO] [1607321000.773203598]:

ROS_INFO is great, but the above takes up a lot of space on my screen. Any way to remove it? Alternatives?

Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52699/remove-info-and-time-from-ros_info/) by [aswin](https://answers.ros.org/users/212/aswin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 528 on 2013-01-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, look at Step 6 in [rosconsole](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosconsole).

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aswin](https://answers.ros.org/users/212/aswin/) on 2013-01-20**:
Awesome! thanks